# What is the proper way to Re-answer?

Tags: discussion

I answered this question [Adding users via Data Loader and activating them in one step](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/768/adding-users-via-data-loader-and-activating-them-in-one-step) 
and after some more investigating, I found another possible solution.

Both my methods do NOT actually answer the question, since what is asked is impossible AFAIK, but my question is:
After i find another way/solution, should I edit my answer to include 2 methods of doing something?

or should it be another answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would rather see the original answer edited than the same user posting multiple answers to the same question.  A lot of times when you have multiple possibilities you can suggest one over the others or provide advice on when to use each or relate them to each other and I think that ties together much better in one post.  Also, it is less cluttered to me.

We can click on the edit and see the diff and we can see the time differences between the edit and the original post as well.

Comment: This is my preferred way to go about things. Typically I write **EDIT** in bold and put the new information there, then use **ORIGINAL ANSWER** further down if some of it is still helpful.